# Accessing file created externally on SD card

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to create a universal android app that will be deployed on a number of provisioned/managed chromeboxes, and I need to be able to reliably identify each device. Because they are managed devices without dedicated user accounts, each reboot generates a new Android ID.

I don't want to have to create a different app for each one with an ID hardcoded, so my thought was to get a bunch of SD cards and from a PC add a simple file to each with an ID in it, and have the app read the file. I can't find a reliable way to access those files from the app though.

Environment.getExternalStorageState() has been depreciated, getExternalFilesDir returns the path to memory dedicated to the app, and nothing I've tried with the MediaStore will show files created outside of the app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural). If that returns 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage.

Comment: Yes, but the path returned is one to storage allocated specifically for the app (android/data/package_name/), not general storage on the SD card. Also, even if I go into that directory and drop a file, it won't show up when I list files within the app.

Comment: "but the path returned is one to storage allocated specifically for the app (android/data/package_name/), not general storage on the SD card" -- you don't have access to "general storage" on Android 10+ anyway. "even if I go into that directory and drop a file, it won't show up when I list files within the app" -- that's a bit surprising. But, if so, then you are pretty much completely screwed for getting at the content automatically. You could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and choose the content that way, but I don't know if that fits your use case.

Comment: Yeah, its essentially a digital sign client, so there isn't any user interaction, and unfortunately we're tied to the chromeboxes, even though I know there are better options. glad I wasn't the only one surprised files weren't listed though, android docs makes it sound like they should be.

Comment: It's possible that's a Chrome OS-specific limitation -- I have not tried that scenario.

Comment: `path returned is one to storage allocated specifically for the app (android/data/package_name/)`. That is no path. A path would be `/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/<packagename>/files`. Now can we trust that you try to do a listing with the right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can't actually access those files from within the app (thanks [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)).

As far as identifiers, with the READ_PHONE_STATE permission you can use the Build.getSerial() function get the hardware serial number, so no SD card needed afterall!